# Sails JS - Connect to MongoDB dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, database

Let's say I have multiple users and each user should connect to its own Mongo database for each request (on the same server).

I'd have N databases on my server, each of them would be for example "mydb_*dynicamicUsername*". So on each request, from my controller or wherever, I'd need to get the name of the user and connect **dynamically** to that database to get the data I need

Is there a way to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Connections are made once you are lifting your app. In order to do that you would have to manually open/close the connections on each request. Sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: and how would you connect to a different db for each request? @yBrodsky

Comment: You have to make a manual connection with some ORM, or with the same waterline if it lets you.